# In AndroidStudio 1.1.0, I can't find the option to export application

Tags: android

I have created my android app and it runs on my connected device. I want to export my android application, but in the file menu, i don't find the 'Export' option at all, nor anywhere else. I had generated the Signed Apk(from the Build->Generate signed Apk option).Is this creating a problem.Please let me know what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: What do you mean by "export" your application?

Comment: Export application to upload on google play

Comment: You're doing the right thing by generating a signed APK file. Just upload it to Google Play Store. Is this causing a problem?

Comment: I don't see why downvoting this simple question makes any sense. See siris answer.

Comment: thankyou, yes siris's answer helped me.this is my first app so the terms are really confusing.....When I uploaded the file to google play, my package name has "com.example" in it which is restricted and so did not upload. Is there an option to change the package name in android studio?

Comment: There are a lot of similar questions here. i.e.: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16804093/android-studio-rename-package

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To publish your Android app on the PlayStore,
On your AndroidStudio do,

- Build -> Generate signed APK
- Create a new App listing on [Developer Console](https://play.google.com/apps/publish/)
- Upload the generated APK
- Publish.

Comment: thanks a lot!!!this is my first app, so all the terms are confusing..thanks a lot for ur guidance!!

Comment: I uploaded the file to google play, but my package name has com.example in it which is restricted. Is there an option to change the package name?

Comment: Package name should be set before starting your project.